# Parsing Json Return getJSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to parse returned json but can't access the data.

Trying to access url value from data array.

The return looks like this below:

```
{ "status_code": 200, "status_txt": "OK", "data": { "long_url": "http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/327231\/best-way-to-display-data-via-json-using-jquery", "url": "http:\/\/bit.ly\/u0GIx8", "hash": "u0GIx8", "global_hash": "7d5klp", "new_hash": 0 } }
```

This won't do the trick:

```
alert(json.data[url]);
```

I'm using jQuery method getJSON to send query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `json.data.url`, or equivalently one of `json['data']['url']`, `json.data['url']` or `json['data'].url`.

Without quotes, `data[url]` refers to the key with the value of the variable `url`, not the key with the name `'url'`. Provide a static string in brackets or use the dot-notation to get the value associated with a static key.

Comment: Or even `json.data['url']`. Just make sure that quotes are added around `url` if you're using square braces.

Comment: How is this different than what the user is trying to evaluate?  Is there just a high likelyhood that `url` is a defined variable in the context of a `getJSON` call?

Comment: @JaredPar If url is not defined (or some random value but not `'url'`), the result will be `undefined` as well.

Comment: @phihag ugg, I see the diff. Been a long day.  Was looking right past the problem in the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when using the `[]` notation to index into JSON objects, you need to provide a string, i.e. a quoted sequence of characters. Without the quotes, it thinks you are trying to use the value of some variable called `url`, which more than likely doesn't exist.

So what you had is the same as:

```
alert(json.data[undefined]);
```

Which obviously won't work.

For clarity's sake, being consistent with which way you access the properties is probably best - use either the `object.property` notation, or the `object['property']` notation.